# Proof Finishing for Upper Triangular Matrix has to have nonzero diagonals for invertibility

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-writing

I'm in the process of writing the proof that an upper triangular matrix is only invertible if it's diagonal are all non-zero values.

Given the matrix $X \in R^{n \times n}$  = 
\begin{bmatrix}
x_{11} & x_{12} & \dots & x_{1n} \\
0      & x_{22} & \dots & x_{2n} \\
\vdots & & \ddots & \vdots \\
0 & \dotsi & 0 & x_{nn}
\end{bmatrix}$

My proof start..

Assume there exists $i \in \{1,\dots,n\}$ such that $x_{ii} = 0$, then we define $i^* = min \{j \mid x_{jj} = 0\}$.

Let $c_1,\dots,c_n$ be the columns of $X$.
We will show that $c_{i^*} \in Span(c_{1},\dots,c_{i-1}).$

How do I show that the columns before $c_{i^*}$ are linearly independent but the addition of $c_{i^*}$ makes it linearly dependent and therefore the rank is at most $n-1$.
Therefore proving it cannot be invertible if there is a 0 on the diagonal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's consider only the left columns of the matrix before column $i^*$,and show they are linearly independent.  Consider the $n \times (i^* -1)$ matrix with these as columns,
$$ A = \begin{bmatrix} c_1 & ... & c_{i^* - 1}  \end{bmatrix} $$
And note that the reduced row echelon form has $x_{ii}=1$ and zeros everywhere else. namely, these vectors are linearly independent.  In particular, these vectors span the space of vectors
$$ \left\{ v \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times 1 }:v =\begin{bmatrix} v_1 \\ \vdots \\ v_{i^* - 1} \\ 0 \\ \vdots \\ 0 \end{bmatrix}  \right\} $$

Now it easily follows that the vector 
$$c_{i^*}=\begin{bmatrix} x_{1, i^*} \\ \vdots \\ x_{i^* - 1, i^*} \\ 0 \\ \vdots \\ 0 \end{bmatrix}$$
is a linear combination of the previous ones

Comment: Couple questions.
Why does $x_{ii} = 1$? and what is this vector $v$?

Comment: Im using set notation, so $v$ is just a general vector of the form where the bottom entries are all $0$.  The reason row echelon form of $A$ is$x_{ii}=1$ and $0$ elsewhere is because each row's pivot is in a different column, so you can use one row to "clear" all the rows above it.  *The best way to understand is try an example I think*.  Proving it rigorously looks very confusing for a very basic fact

Answer (score 1):

Here is a shorter proof, but it makes use of determinants. The matrix $X$ is invertible if and only if its determinant is not equal to $0$. Since $$\text{det}(X) = x_{1,1}x_{2,2} \dotsm x_{n,n}\ ,$$
$\text{det}(X) = 0$ if, and only if, one of the diagonal entries of $X$ is null.